# TimeoutException in rest call

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices

I am trying to call an api like below :

```
ExternalApiRequest.builder()
                .name(ApiRequestCode.MyApiRequest.toString())
                .appName("MY_SERVICES")
                .transformFunction(MyResponse::myApiResponseObj)
                .headers(headers)
                .urlString(calliingServicesURL)
                .timeOut(callingServicesTimeOut)
                .build();
```

However I am getting the below error frequently not always :

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 1000ms in 'lift' (and no fallback has been configured)
u2028 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:289)
u2028 Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ 
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
u2028 |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/callingapiurlhere" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
u2028 Stack trace:
u2028 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:289)
u2028 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:274)
u2028 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:396)
u2028 at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onNext(StrictSubscriber.java:89)
u2028 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73)
u2028 at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:117)
u2028 at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
u2028 at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
u2028 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
u2028 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
u2028 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
u2028 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
u2028 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
u2028 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My relevant properties :

```
callingservices:
  baseUri: /some/path/
  url: ${my.baseUrl}${callingservices.baseUri}
  uriPostfix: /definition
  timeOut: 1000
```

When I am simply hitting the URL from postman then no issues observed. However when I run a load testing script sometimes I get this error.

Can someone suggest why I am getting this intermittent error.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting this error because your API is unable to respond within 1 second during your load test.

Comment: @g00glen00b Yes true !

Comment: So, does that answer your question or did you expect something else to happen?

Comment: @g00glen00b : I want to find out why such intermittent behavior. Timeout initially was 800 i increased it to 1000 now. Still the issue is there.

Comment: But how do you know that 1000ms will be enough? You're load testing, so perhaps your API can't handle that many requests in 800ms nor in 1000ms.